# Deserializing XML with HTML tags

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to deserialize an XML file, and it works fine except for nodes that contain HTML tags. Here is a snippet from the XML file:

```
<article mdate="2011-12-29" key="tr/trier/MI99-02" publtype="informal publication">
    <author>Friedemann Leibfritz</author>
    <title>A LMI-Based Algorithm for Designing Suboptimal Static H<sub>2</sub>/H<sub>infinity</sub> Output Feedback Controllers</title>
    <journal>Universit&auml;t Trier, Mathematik/Informatik, Forschungsbericht</journal>
    <volume>99-02</volume>
    <year>1999</year>
</article>
```

Then, I am getting the error:

```
{"Unexpected node type Element. ReadElementString method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content. Line 1148, position 64."}
```

The error occurs at:

```
A LMI-Based Algorithm for Designing Suboptimal Static H2/Hinfinity Output Feedback Controllers
```

where HTML tags sub and /sub exist.

Is there a way to deserialize the title node as a whole, ignoring the HTML tags? Below is a portion of my code:

```
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
   DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
   XmlResolver = new LocalXhtmlXmlResolver()
};

XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "dblp";
xRoot.IsNullable = true;
XmlSerializer deserializer;
XmlReader textReader;

deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Entity.Article>), xRoot);
textReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, readerSettings);
List<Entity.Article> articleList;
articleList = (List<Entity.Article>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
textReader.Close();
```

Any help would be very much appreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your XML is not properly escaped. The parser has no way of knowing that those tags aren't meant to be part of the XML document, and when they are treated as such, your XML is invalid, because an element is nested within the value of another element.

That XML snippet, correctly escaped would be

```
<article mdate="2011-12-29" key="tr/trier/MI99-02" publtype="informal publication">
    <author>Friedemann Leibfritz</author>
    <title>A LMI-Based Algorithm for Designing Suboptimal Static H&lt;sub&gt;2&lt;/sub&gt;/H&lt;sub&gt;infinity&lt;/sub&gt; Output Feedback Controllers</title>
    <journal>Universit&auml;t Trier, Mathematik/Informatik, Forschungsbericht</journal>
    <volume>99-02</volume>
    <year>1999</year>
</article>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! It is a requirement not to amend the XML file. Also, the XML file is roughtly 1.2GB huge, and there are probably other HTML tags undiscovered yet (e.g., <sup></sup>). Is there any way to skip such elements instead?

Comment: You *don't* currently have a valid XML file, you can't just skip the parts you don't like - what you're asking is akin to writing a C# application with random "{"'s strewn throughout the source code and asking the compiler to just skip the ones that shouldn't be there.

What you *could* do is process the text file, trying to replace known bad HTML tags with properly escaped ones, but this is dangerous in and of itself - are you *sure* there's no XML `<sub>` element in the file? What about `<strike>`? `<head>`? The real problem here is that the XML needs to be generated properly.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments to the previous answer point out- as developers we don't always have the luxury of formatting the XML prior to deserialization. There is a much more elegant solution, in my opinion, that satisfies the original question.

### Serializer

```
public static T ParseXml<T>(this string @this) where T : class
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.UnknownElement += Serializer_UnknownElement;
    return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(@this)) as T;            
}
```

### Handle Problematic Fields

```
private static void Serializer_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ObjectBeingDeserialized is Article article)
    {
        if (e.Element.Name == "title")
        {
            article.Title_Custom = e.Element.InnerXml;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

### Modifications to Article Class

```
public class Article{
  // include your other fields that are not problematic
  public string Title_Custom { get; set; }
}
```

### Usage

```
var myArticles = articlesXmlString.Parse<List<Article>>();
Console.Out(myArticles[0].Title_Custom); // "A LMI-Based Algorithm for Designing Suboptimal Static H<sub>2</sub>/H<sub>infinity</sub> Output Feedback Controllers"
```

Because the name of the property is now `Title_Custom` it will naturally be skipped as part of the deserialization process. The `Serializer_UnknownElement` method will then read in the `<title>` field as an unknown field. Then, you simply pull the entire contents of the inner XML.

The inclusion of `<sup>` *will* trip the `Serializer_UnknownElement` as well, but as you have no condition for it, it will skip over it.

The net result is that `Title_Custom` will now contain the full HTML snippet as expected.